# I want to setup two mirrors in my maven settings xml, need help do not know what i am doing wrong here

Tags: java, maven

I am new with Maven and working with setting up 2 different mirrors for my maven project such that one should pick from my internal mirror and if not found then pick it from the central maven repository.

So, far I have configured my setting.xml with values as below:

```
 <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>mirror</id>
            <name>name</name>
            <url>URL</url>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
        <mirror>
            <id>public</id>
            <name>Public Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <mirrorOf>*,!mirror</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
```

Is there something else that I have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with * at the first mapping. It will match everything to the first URL.
Either change the order of mirrors and keep the * at the last, or remove the * and put something more specific.
For syntax you may follow below examples:

```
* = everything
external:* = everything not on the localhost and not file based.
repo,repo1 = repo or repo1
*,!repo1 = everything except repo1
```

Comment: Doing that is still not taking the alternative mirror, it tries to download everything from only central repository